# ng-show hanging my whole application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-show, ionic-popover

i am getting strange problem that when ever i am trying to put ng-show inside my popover.html , my app got hangs. and when i comment it my app works fine. i am realyy not getting that whats going wrong inside my code.

here is my popover.html :-

```html
<ion-popover-view> <ion-content>

<div ng-show="showsettingButton()">
 <ion-item menu-close ng-click="logout()"> Sign Out <span
  class="item-icon-right"><i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></span> </ion-item>

 <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.profile"> Settings <span
  class="item-icon-right"><i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></span> </ion-item>
</div>

<div class="list" ng-repeat="title in Titlelist">
 <a class="item"
  ng-click="openpage(title.page_title,title.page_content)">
  {{title.page_title}} </a>
</div>

</ion-content> </ion-popover-view>
```

here is my functions in controller :-

```js
app
  .controller(
    'MenuCtrl',
    function($scope, LocalStorage, $stateParams, $rootScope,
      $state, store, ngCart, $window, $ionicHistory,
      DataService, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $http,
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicPopover) {
                  
                  $scope.showsettingButton = function() {
      $scope.popover.hide();
      if (LocalStorage.getData("userId")) {
       if (LocalStorage.getData("userId") !== "undefiened") {
        DataService.setbooleanIsUserLoggedIn(true);
       } else {
        DataService.setbooleanIsUserLoggedIn(false);
       }
      } else {
       DataService.setbooleanIsUserLoggedIn(false);
      }
      return DataService.getbooleanIsUserLoggedIn()
     }
                  
                  $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html', {
      scope : $scope,
     }).then(function(popover) {
      $scope.popover = popover;
     });

     $scope.openpage = function(Pagetitle, Pagecontent) {
      $scope.popover.hide();
      var jsonObject = {
       title : Pagetitle,
       content : Pagecontent
      }
      DataService.addcontent(jsonObject)
      $state.go('app.extraPage');
     }
                    
                  });
```

if i comment this line

```html
<div ng-show="showsettingButton()"> <div/>
```

, my app works fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that `LocalStorage.getData("userId")` is the line hanging? Perhaps it's not being able to fetch the results.

Comment: Can you share with us the full code (include the dependencies like `LocalStorage`) or (even better) add a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: in-place of ng-show try ng-if ..

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div ng-if="showsettingButton()">
 <ion-item menu-close ng-click="logout()"> Sign Out <span
  class="item-icon-right"><i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></span> </ion-item>

 <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="app.profile"> Settings <span
  class="item-icon-right"><i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></span> </ion-item>
</div>
```